# Конвертер в Python

Tags: python, конвертация

Только начинаю учить питон, пытаюсь написать код для конвертера, который бы переводил введенные в `input()` значения сантиметров и килограммов в дюймы и фунты. `return` работает только у первого конвертера, и то выводит только введенное в `input()` значение, игнорируя `/2.54`. Второго конвертера как будто вообще не существует

## конвертер для сантиметров

```py
santi = int(input(3))
def convert_santi(santi):
    return santi/2.54
    
inch = convert_santi
print(inch)
```

## конвертер для килограммов

```py
kilo = int(input(4))
def convert_kilo(kilo):
    return kilo*2.2
    
pound = convert_kilo
print(pound)
```

Comment: Вместо int() поставь float().

Comment: Вообще странно, что что-то выводит разумное. Вызов функции не производится нормальным образом - нет передачи параметра.

Comment: @Сергей а функция ничего и не выводит. Это вывод input(), а не функции.

Comment: @Эникейщик, `print(inch)` что-то, да должно вывести...

Comment: @Сергей оно и выводит кое что

Comment: @Эникейщик, это я и имел в виду. Я не писал, что что-то выводит функция, но что её вызывают неверно (а далее `print` выводит не то, что ожидают).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вызов функций организовывается так

```py
def convert_santi(santi):
    return santi/2.54

def convert_kilo(kilo):
    return kilo*2.2

inch = convert_santi(int(input())) # 3
pound = convert_kilo(int(input())) # 3
print(inch, pound)
```

смысл состоит в том, что вы описываете функцию и некоторые манипуляции внутри без привязки к внешним данным. Далее вы вызываете эту функцию и передаете на вход (то что в скобках) данные, над которыми будут эти манипуляции производиться.

Это все вызовы функций:

```py
convert_santi() # error - входной параметр обязателен
convert_santi("abc") # error - к строку нельзя применять деление
convert_santi(3) # 1.1811023622047243
convert_santi(int(input())) # будет ожидаться ввод данных
```

#### Что случится если не использовать скобки при вызове функции

Ошибку вы не получите, но и результат для вас будет неожиданным

```py
a = convert_kilo
print(a)

# OUT
# <function convert_kilo at 0x104df20e0>
```

скорей всего это не то, что вы ожидаете